# How to access the url of file when app launched from 'share' menu in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a pdf that I want to analyze when I open it with my swiftui app (iOS 14.1).
I've configured the info.plist of my app to declare it can open pdf files

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>pdf</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>app.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>public.pdf</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.pdf</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>public.pdf</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>com.apple.ostype</key>
                <string>PDF</string>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>pdf</string>
                </array>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <string>application/pdf</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now, when I click on the pdf file (in file manager or in an email), and select my app in the 'share' menu, it opens my app exactly how I wanted.

But I have no clue about how to get the url of the file (or directly the file content) inside my app.

I've tried using .onOpenURL modifier but it never seems to be called.
Is it only called from schemes url?

Comment: So your app is kind of pdf editor or something like that, you open a pdf file through your app, you receive the file, but you need url of that, right?

Comment: Exactly, it's a kind of editor (I won't really modify the input file). And I need the url of the pdf for updating some data in my app.

Comment: So, if you do not want modify the input file things get much easier but I think you can also modify it, can you show some code that how your app work on getting a file? it would help to solve issue if we could have some code to works